# Trying to fscanf with 2d array that uses calloc()

Tags: c

I'm trying to read text from a file and print it in the terminal while using dynamic memory(?), but as soon as I use calloc the code crashes. I'm new to C so I don't know what's wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void filecheck(FILE*);
int main(void){
    int i=0;
    char** text=(char**)calloc(50,sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<50;i++) text[i]=(char*)calloc(50,sizeof(char));
    FILE *file = fopen("F1.txt","r");
    filecheck(file);
    while(fscanf(file,"%s", text[i])!=EOF){
        printf("%s\n",text[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(text);
    return 0;
}
void filecheck(FILE*file){
if(file==NULL){
        printf("Problem");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger (and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...) to understand the behavior of your program. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) for the documentation of *every* function (like `calloc`, `fopen`, etc....) you did not define

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set `i` to `0` before you use it in the 2nd while loop.  This cause the segmentation fault when you access text out of bounds.  I addressed that issue below by using the same type of for loop that you used to initialize the array in the first place.

Bonus items:

0. Reformatted code for readability (to me) with spaces and moved * next to variable instead of next to type.
1. Introduced a couple of defines to replace your magic 50 numbers.
2. Moved filecheck() before main() so you don't need the declaration.
3. filecheck() now return a status code.  This allows main() to free memory on failure which was technically a memory leak (even if the OS does this for you).
4. Check return value of calloc.
5. Use a status variable to hold exit code.  This allows for clean-up to be shared in both normal and failure case.
6. Used variable instead of type as argument to sizeof.
7. Declare the variable as part of each for loop instead of reusing a variable.  Reuse is not wrong, btw, but I think it's a good practice even if you use the same variable name.
8. fgets() instead of fscanf().  fscanf() is subject to buffer overflow when reading strings.  Note: fscanf() reads a sequence of non-white-space characters, while fgets() read a line including the '\n'. Removed the the '\n' in the subsequent printf().
9. Only read at most ARR_LEN strings.
10. fclose() file descriptor (even if OS would do this for you).
11. Free the memory you allocate for text[i].  It is technically a memory leak if you don't (even if the OS frees it for you).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_LEN 50
#define STR_LEN 50

int filecheck(FILE *file) {
    if(!file) {
        printf("Problem");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void) {
    int status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    char **text = calloc(ARR_LEN, sizeof(*text));
    if(!text)
       goto out;
    for(int i=0; i < ARR_LEN; i++) {
        text[i] = calloc(STR_LEN, sizeof(**text));
        if(!text[i])
           goto out; 
    }
    FILE *file = fopen("F1.txt","r");
    if(filecheck(file) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
       goto out;
    for(int i=0; (i < ARR_LEN) && fgets(text[i], STR_SIZE, file); i++)
        printf("%s",text[i]);
    status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
out:
    if(file) fclose(file);
    for(int i=0; i<ARR_LEN; i++)
        free(text[i]);
    free(text);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, replacing while(fscanf(file,"%s", text[i])!=EOF) with for(i=0; fscanf(file,"%s", text[i]) != EOF; i++) and freeing text[i] made it work for some reason

Comment: Because the for loop sets i to 0.

Comment: as both dimensions of array are fixed, whouldn't be simpler to define it as `char text[ARR_LEN][STR_LEN]` ?

Comment: `fgets(text[i], ARR_SIZE, file)` -> `fgets(text[i], STR_LEN, file)`

Comment: @tstanisl yes, as long as it's really static and STR_LEN * ARR_LEN << stack size.  You could also use a char text[ARR_LEN * STR_LEN] and just index it correctly.  I use that trick to reduce number of mallocs calls some times when the size is dynamic.

Comment: "Because the for loop sets i to 0." does while set it to something else then? I thought that because I had int i=0 then it would be also 0 in the while statement.
"as both dimensions of array are fixed, whouldn't be simpler to define it as char text[ARR_LEN][STR_LEN]" Yes, usually I would do it like that, but I'm learning about dynamic memory so I wanted to use calloc here

Comment: Your while loop did not set and that was the problem.  So in the first iteration i=50 and `printf("%s\n",text[i])` which is out of bounds.

Comment: You could do it one allocation using a pointer to array:
```char (*text)[STR_LEN] = calloc(ARR_LEN, sizeof(*text));```

Comment: `status` should be one of `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status

Comment: @tstanisl you are right and I fixed it.  Do you know of any platform where 0 is not success?  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Other error (except `i` not set to `0`) is that the function `fscanf` returns a number of scanned arguments. So you should use:

```
while (fscanf(file,"%s", text[i])!=1) {
   ...
}
```

Moreover, individual `text[i]` are never freed and leak.